# Improve query performance: add indexes

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a query that performs unacceptable. It runs more than 60'000 times within a business critical operation and I have problems tuning it. Will greatly appreciate help. Please, if possible, recommend indexes that can be added.
Actual query plan is [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1ArLONZI).

```
EXEC sp_executesql 
     N'SELECT T1.AccountRRef, 
       T1.Fld7716RRef, 
       T1.Value1_TYPE, 
       T1.Value1_RTRef, 
       T1.Value1_RRRef, 
       @P1, 
       0x01, 
       @P2, 
       T1.Fld7714RRef, 
       CAST(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(T1.Fld7719BalanceDt_ AS NUMERIC(27, 3)), 0.0)) AS NUMERIC(33, 3)), 
       CAST(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(T1.Fld7719BalanceDt_ AS NUMERIC(27, 3)), 0.0)) AS NUMERIC(33, 3)), 
       CAST(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(T1.Fld7717BalanceDt_ AS NUMERIC(27, 2)), 0.0)) AS NUMERIC(33, 2)), 
       CAST(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(T1.Fld7720BalanceDt_ AS NUMERIC(27, 2)), 0.0)) AS NUMERIC(33, 2)), 
       CAST(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(T1.Fld7721BalanceDt_ AS NUMERIC(27, 2)), 0.0)) AS NUMERIC(33, 2)), 
       CAST(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(T1.Fld7722BalanceDt_ AS NUMERIC(27, 2)), 0.0)) AS NUMERIC(33, 2))
FROM
(
    SELECT T2.AccountRRef AS AccountRRef, 
           T2.Fld7716RRef AS Fld7716RRef, 
           T2.Value1_TYPE AS Value1_TYPE, 
           T2.Value1_RTRef AS Value1_RTRef, 
           T2.Value1_RRRef AS Value1_RRRef, 
           T2.Fld7714RRef AS Fld7714RRef,
           CASE
               WHEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7717Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) IS NULL
               THEN 0.0
               WHEN MAX(T9._Kind) = 0.0
                    OR MAX(T9._Kind) = 2.0
                    AND CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7717Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) > 0.0
               THEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7717Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2))
               ELSE 0.0
           END AS Fld7717BalanceDt_,
           CASE
               WHEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7719Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 3)) IS NULL
               THEN 0.0
               WHEN MAX(T9._Kind) = 0.0
                    OR MAX(T9._Kind) = 2.0
                    AND CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7719Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 3)) > 0.0
               THEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7719Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 3))
               ELSE 0.0
           END AS Fld7719BalanceDt_,
           CASE
               WHEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7720Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) IS NULL
               THEN 0.0
               WHEN MAX(T9._Kind) = 0.0
                    OR MAX(T9._Kind) = 2.0
                    AND CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7720Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) > 0.0
               THEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7720Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2))
               ELSE 0.0
           END AS Fld7720BalanceDt_,
           CASE
               WHEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7722Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) IS NULL
               THEN 0.0
               WHEN MAX(T9._Kind) = 0.0
                    OR MAX(T9._Kind) = 2.0
                    AND CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7722Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) > 0.0
               THEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7722Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2))
               ELSE 0.0
           END AS Fld7722BalanceDt_,
           CASE
               WHEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7721Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) IS NULL
               THEN 0.0
               WHEN MAX(T9._Kind) = 0.0
                    OR MAX(T9._Kind) = 2.0
                    AND CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7721Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) > 0.0
               THEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7721Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2))
               ELSE 0.0
           END AS Fld7721BalanceDt_, 
           MAX(T9._Kind) AS AccKind_
    FROM
    (
        SELECT T3._AccountRRef AS AccountRRef, 
               T3._Fld7716RRef AS Fld7716RRef, 
               T3._Value1_TYPE AS Value1_TYPE, 
               T3._Value1_RTRef AS Value1_RTRef, 
               T3._Value1_RRRef AS Value1_RRRef, 
               T3._Fld7714RRef AS Fld7714RRef, 
               T3._Fld7717 AS Fld7717Balance_, 
               T3._Fld7719 AS Fld7719Balance_, 
               T3._Fld7720 AS Fld7720Balance_, 
               T3._Fld7722 AS Fld7722Balance_, 
               T3._Fld7721 AS Fld7721Balance_
        FROM dbo._AccRgAT17745 T3
             INNER JOIN #tt64 T4 WITH(NOLOCK) ON T4._IDRRef = T3._AccountRRef
                                                 AND T4._LineNo1 = @P3
                                                 AND T4._Cnt = @P4
        WHERE T3._Fld11344 = @P5
              AND T3._Fld7716RRef = @P6
              AND T3._Value1_TYPE = 0x08
              AND T3._Value1_RTRef = 0x0000002E
              AND T3._Value1_RRRef IN(@P7)
             AND T3._Fld7714RRef = @P8
             AND T3._Period = @P9
             AND (T3._Fld7717 <> @P10
                  OR T3._Fld7719 <> @P11
                  OR T3._Fld7720 <> @P12
                  OR T3._Fld7722 <> @P13
                  OR T3._Fld7721 <> @P14)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT T5._AccountDtRRef AS AccountRRef, 
               T5._Fld7716DtRRef AS Fld7716RRef, 
               T6._Value_TYPE AS Value1_TYPE, 
               T6._Value_RTRef AS Value1_RTRef, 
               T6._Value_RRRef AS Value1_RRRef, 
               T5._Fld7714RRef AS Fld7714RRef, 
               CAST(-T5._Fld7717 AS NUMERIC(21, 2)) AS Fld7717Balance_, 
               CAST(-T5._Fld7719Dt AS NUMERIC(21, 3)) AS Fld7719Balance_, 
               CAST(-T5._Fld7720Dt AS NUMERIC(21, 2)) AS Fld7720Balance_, 
               CAST(-T5._Fld7722Dt AS NUMERIC(21, 2)) AS Fld7722Balance_, 
               CAST(-T5._Fld7721Dt AS NUMERIC(21, 2)) AS Fld7721Balance_
        FROM dbo._AccRg7713 T5
             INNER JOIN dbo._AccRgED7749 T6 ON T6._RecorderTRef = T5._RecorderTRef
                                               AND T6._RecorderRRef = T5._RecorderRRef
                                               AND T6._LineNo = T5._LineNo
                                               AND T6._Period = T5._Period
                                               AND T6._Correspond = @P15
                                               AND T6._KindRRef = @P16
                                               AND (T6._Period > @P17
                                                    OR T6._Period = @P18
                                                    AND (T6._RecorderTRef > 0x000000B7
                                                         OR T6._RecorderTRef = 0x000000B7
                                                         AND T6._RecorderRRef >= @P19))
                                               AND T6._Period < @P20
        WHERE T5._Fld11344 = @P21
              AND T6._Fld11344 = @P22
              AND T5._Active = 0x01
              AND T5._AccountDtRRef <> @P23
              AND T5._AccountDtRRef IN(@P24)
             AND T5._Fld7716DtRRef = @P25
             AND T6._Value_TYPE = 0x08
             AND T6._Value_RTRef = 0x0000002E
             AND T6._Value_RRRef IN(@P26)
        AND T5._Fld7714RRef = @P27
        AND (T5._Period > @P28
             OR T5._Period = @P29
             AND (T5._RecorderTRef > 0x000000B7
                  OR T5._RecorderTRef = 0x000000B7
                  AND T5._RecorderRRef >= @P30))
        AND T5._Period < @P31
        UNION ALL
        SELECT T7._AccountCtRRef AS AccountRRef, 
               T7._Fld7716CtRRef AS Fld7716RRef, 
               T8._Value_TYPE AS Value1_TYPE, 
               T8._Value_RTRef AS Value1_RTRef, 
               T8._Value_RRRef AS Value1_RRRef, 
               T7._Fld7714RRef AS Fld7714RRef, 
               CAST(T7._Fld7717 AS NUMERIC(21, 2)) AS Fld7717Balance_, 
               CAST(T7._Fld7719Ct AS NUMERIC(21, 3)) AS Fld7719Balance_, 
               CAST(T7._Fld7720Ct AS NUMERIC(21, 2)) AS Fld7720Balance_, 
               CAST(T7._Fld7722Ct AS NUMERIC(21, 2)) AS Fld7722Balance_, 
               CAST(T7._Fld7721Ct AS NUMERIC(21, 2)) AS Fld7721Balance_
        FROM dbo._AccRg7713 T7
             INNER JOIN dbo._AccRgED7749 T8 ON T8._RecorderTRef = T7._RecorderTRef
                                               AND T8._RecorderRRef = T7._RecorderRRef
                                               AND T8._LineNo = T7._LineNo
                                               AND T8._Period = T7._Period
                                               AND T8._Correspond = @P32
                                               AND T8._KindRRef = @P33
                                               AND (T8._Period > @P34
                                                    OR T8._Period = @P35
                                                    AND (T8._RecorderTRef > 0x000000B7
                                                         OR T8._RecorderTRef = 0x000000B7
                                                         AND T8._RecorderRRef >= @P36))
                                               AND T8._Period < @P37
        WHERE T7._Fld11344 = @P38
              AND T8._Fld11344 = @P39
              AND T7._Active = 0x01
              AND T7._AccountCtRRef <> @P40
              AND T7._AccountCtRRef IN(@P41)
             AND T7._Fld7716CtRRef = @P42
             AND T8._Value_TYPE = 0x08
             AND T8._Value_RTRef = 0x0000002E
             AND T8._Value_RRRef IN(@P43)
        AND T7._Fld7714RRef = @P44
        AND (T7._Period > @P45
             OR T7._Period = @P46
             AND (T7._RecorderTRef > 0x000000B7
                  OR T7._RecorderTRef = 0x000000B7
                  AND T7._RecorderRRef >= @P47))
        AND T7._Period < @P48
    ) T2
    INNER JOIN dbo._Acc7 T9 ON T9._IDRRef = T2.AccountRRef
    WHERE T9._Fld11344 = @P49
    GROUP BY T2.AccountRRef, 
             T2.Fld7716RRef, 
             T2.Value1_TYPE, 
             T2.Value1_RTRef, 
             T2.Value1_RRRef, 
             T2.Fld7714RRef
    HAVING CASE
               WHEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7717Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) IS NULL
               THEN 0.0
               WHEN MAX(T9._Kind) = 0.0
                    OR MAX(T9._Kind) = 2.0
                    AND CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7717Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) > 0.0
               THEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7717Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2))
               ELSE 0.0
           END <> 0.0
           OR CASE
                  WHEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7719Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 3)) IS NULL
                  THEN 0.0
                  WHEN MAX(T9._Kind) = 0.0
                       OR MAX(T9._Kind) = 2.0
                       AND CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7719Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 3)) > 0.0
                  THEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7719Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 3))
                  ELSE 0.0
              END <> 0.0
           OR CASE
                  WHEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7720Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) IS NULL
                  THEN 0.0
                  WHEN MAX(T9._Kind) = 0.0
                       OR MAX(T9._Kind) = 2.0
                       AND CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7720Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) > 0.0
                  THEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7720Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2))
                  ELSE 0.0
              END <> 0.0
           OR CASE
                  WHEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7722Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) IS NULL
                  THEN 0.0
                  WHEN MAX(T9._Kind) = 0.0
                       OR MAX(T9._Kind) = 2.0
                       AND CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7722Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) > 0.0
                  THEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7722Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2))
                  ELSE 0.0
              END <> 0.0
           OR CASE
                  WHEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7721Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) IS NULL
                  THEN 0.0
                  WHEN MAX(T9._Kind) = 0.0
                       OR MAX(T9._Kind) = 2.0
                       AND CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7721Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2)) > 0.0
                  THEN CAST(SUM(T2.Fld7721Balance_) AS NUMERIC(27, 2))
                  ELSE 0.0
              END <> 0.0
) T1
GROUP BY T1.AccountRRef, 
         T1.Fld7716RRef, 
         T1.Value1_TYPE, 
         T1.Value1_RTRef, 
         T1.Value1_RRRef, 
         T1.Fld7714RRef', 
     N'@P1 datetime2(3),@P2 varbinary(16),@P3 numeric(10),@P4 numeric(10),@P5 numeric(10),@P6 varbinary(16),@P7 varbinary(16),@P8 varbinary(16),@P9 datetime2(3),@P10 numeric(10),@P11 numeric(10),@P12 numeric(10),@P13 numeric(10),@P14 numeric(10),@P15 numeric(10),@P16 varbinary(16),@P17 datetime2(3),@P18 datetime2(3),@P19 varbinary(16),@P20 datetime2(3),@P21 numeric(10),@P22 numeric(10),@P23 varbinary(16),@P24 varbinary(16),@P25 varbinary(16),@P26 varbinary(16),@P27 varbinary(16),@P28 datetime2(3),@P29 datetime2(3),@P30 varbinary(16),@P31 datetime2(3),@P32 numeric(10),@P33 varbinary(16),@P34 datetime2(3),@P35 datetime2(3),@P36 varbinary(16),@P37 datetime2(3),@P38 numeric(10),@P39 numeric(10),@P40 varbinary(16),@P41 varbinary(16),@P42 varbinary(16),@P43 varbinary(16),@P44 varbinary(16),@P45 datetime2(3),@P46 datetime2(3),@P47 varbinary(16),@P48 datetime2(3),@P49 numeric(10)', 
     '2001-01-01 00:00:00', 
     0x00000000000000000000000000000000, 
     1, 
     1, 
     0, 
     0xBA860019BBEB53FA11DF957A04B76BA6, 
     0xB909000D6143BD1F11DBCE550BA89CDC, 
     0x916F000C6EEACA2411DB965CAF889601, 
     '4019-12-31 00:00:00', 
     0, 
     0, 
     0, 
     0, 
     0, 
     0, 
     0xA2D9EF0AD9924E764E73FB1C43E874EE, 
     '4019-10-01 08:00:00', 
     '4019-10-01 08:00:00', 
     0x80C51402EC06156111E9E509FEC8AFE8, 
     '4019-12-31 00:00:00', 
     0, 
     0, 
     0x00000000000000000000000000000000, 
     0xA36F5219F3882D59474C2B8DF0E06657, 
     0xBA860019BBEB53FA11DF957A04B76BA6, 
     0xB909000D6143BD1F11DBCE550BA89CDC, 
     0x916F000C6EEACA2411DB965CAF889601, 
     '4019-10-01 08:00:00', 
     '4019-10-01 08:00:00', 
     0x80C51402EC06156111E9E509FEC8AFE8, 
     '4019-12-31 00:00:00', 
     1, 
     0xA2D9EF0AD9924E764E73FB1C43E874EE, 
     '4019-10-01 08:00:00', 
     '4019-10-01 08:00:00', 
     0x80C51402EC06156111E9E509FEC8AFE8, 
     '4019-12-31 00:00:00', 
     0, 
     0, 
     0x00000000000000000000000000000000, 
     0xA36F5219F3882D59474C2B8DF0E06657, 
     0xBA860019BBEB53FA11DF957A04B76BA6, 
     0xB909000D6143BD1F11DBCE550BA89CDC, 
     0x916F000C6EEACA2411DB965CAF889601, 
     '4019-10-01 08:00:00', 
     '4019-10-01 08:00:00', 
     0x80C51402EC06156111E9E509FEC8AFE8, 
     '4019-12-31 00:00:00', 
     0;
```

Comment: Starting point could be working on removing implicit conversion.

Comment: Perhaps you could change the sorting of the columns in `ix_test` to avoid the database sorting for you?

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: I'm assuming since your posting the query plan on brentozar.com that you've run his sp_BlitzIndex script?  it looks like you're using 9 tables, you'd want to look at indexing the columns that are being hit by the where clauses.  Brent mentions his rule of 5's as a jumping off point:   
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/index-tuning-week-my-d-e-a-t-h-method-for-tuning-indexes/